# Ember store.findAll is reloading view and store.query is not

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

At the moment, when an article is added to the store, my view is not updated when I use store.query(), filtering server side, in my route but it's updated when I use store.findAll() with filtering client side.

With findAll, filtering client side

```
//route.js
model() {
return this.get('store').findAll('article');
}

//controller.js
articleSorted: computed.filterBy('model', 'isPublished', true),
```

and with query filtering server side

```
//route.js
model() {
  return this.get('store').query('article', { q: 'isPublished' }),
}
```

**The fact is that findAll is reloading and query is not.**

I've found this but did not understand
https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/issues/15256

Comment: What do you mean by "reloading"? Are you struggling with model hook not being executed again if `isPublished` changes? Please add some more details of what you expect and what you see instead.

Comment: Can you use `peekAll` instead?

Comment: Your github link provides thorough explanation over how to make query to act like live array pointing to store.

Comment: With query : when a data is added to my store my view list is not updated with the new element so the view is not 'RELOADING'

Answer (score 5):

thanks for the question. I'll try to answer it the best I can but it would seem like some more documentation should be added to the Ember Guides to explain this situation

Essentially `this.store.findAll()` and `this.store.query()` do two very different things. `findAll()` is designed to be a representation of **all** of the entities (articles in your case) so it makes sense that the result will automatically update as the store finds more articles it should care about. It does this because it doesn't return an array of articles, it returns a `DS.RecordArray` that will automatically update.

`query()` on the other hand is designed to ask the backend every time what it expects the result to be, and you are usually passing a number of parameters to the `query()` call that the backend is using to find or filter results. It would be impossible for the frontend to know exactly how the backend interprets these query parameters so it is not possible for it to "auto-update" when a new article is added that would satisfy the same query.

Does that make sense? Would you like me to go into any more detail?

Comment: Thank you for your time and your answer. Considering that, is there a solution or a workaround using query ? Thanks

Comment: the solution when you're using query is that you need to probably reload the model when you know that it needs to be updated. Does your use case allow for that?

Comment: Yeah it does, but i do not understand how am i supposed to reload the model, codedly speaking

Comment: So if you're in a route you can use this.refresh() https://api.emberjs.com/ember/3.10/classes/Route/methods/refresh?anchor=refresh or you can use the router service to navigate to the route again which will reload the model hook. I'm assuming that the data is being fetched in a model hook yes?

Comment: Did this help you @elo? If so can I get you to accept my answer 

Answer (score 3):

When using `store.query` to fetch data from the server, the view can still be auto-updated with new client-created store data *before* it's saved to the server, by using a "live" record array for it.

While data from `store.query` isn't live, data from `store.peekAll` is, so you can query first but then leverage `store.peekAll` for display. You can query before setting your model to the peeked data, or keep your query as the model but use some other property of peeked data for display. The important part is to ensure the query is resolved before peeking at the store.

Example based on the current code in your question:

```
// route.js
beforeModel() {
  // using return ensures this hook waits for the promise to resolve before moving on
  return this.store.query('article', { q: 'isPublished' });
}

model() {
  // Queried server data should now be available to peek at locally, 
  // so we can set the model to a live version of it. Don't append filterBy here,
  // otherwise it will no longer be live.
  return this.store.peekAll('article');
}

// controller.js
// seemingly redundant filter since using query, but needed if there are other records
// in the store that shouldn't be displayed, and is recomputed when 
// a record is added or removed from the store-based model
articleSorted: filterBy('model', 'isPublished', true) // filterBy imported from '@ember/object/computed'

// template.hbs
{{#each articleSorted as |article|}}
    {{!-- this displayed list should update as new records are added to the store --}}
    {{article}}
{{/each}}
```

Note that *after* a new record is saved to the server, the query can be updated via its `update` method or via a route refresh. This will re-run the query and get the updated results from the server. If the query is the model, that would look like `model.update()`. If it was saved to `someOtherProperty`, then `someOtherProperty.update()`. In either case, `route.refresh()` could be used instead to re-run all route hooks.

Some specific comments/examples that I think are helpful:

- https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/issues/15256#issuecomment-302894768
- https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/issues/15256#issuecomment-302906077
- https://github.com/pouchdb-community/ember-pouch/issues/232#issuecomment-428927114